# Combine in pairs through a loop by directories in Python?

Tags: python

---

**The main process is the following:**

One main folder A with B,C,D... subfolders. This main folder has **new** under consideration files.**Most** of the subfolders have shps.

There is one other main folder though. Let's call it K with L,M,N.. subfolders.These subfolders are the corresponding from the other subfolders of the other folder with the **new** files.

The subfolders from **A** have the same names with the ones from **K** although **K** may have more that we don't need.

I want the user to insert the directory of the main `A` folder and read the first shp from the first subfolder (if it exists an shp there) then go to the other `old` main folder and check the corresponding subfolder, get the `shp` from there *and do some comparisons between them and print the results*(the italics parts i have already solved them)and then continue with the rest of the `new` folder's subfolders accordingly.If in one subfolder there is not an shp it should print:'folder name' has no shp. and continue with the rest.

How should i do it?

I have tried this code where does some part of it: It stores to a list each shp in every subfolder but from the first main folder. It needs from the two main folders for the comparison to be successful.

```
import fiona
from pprint import pprint
import os

rootdir = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\a' # path to the root directory you walk
    sfiles = [] # a list with all the .shp files
    for entry in os.listdir(rootdir):
        dirpath = os.path.join(rootdir, entry)
        if os.path.isdir(dirpath): 
            for file in os.listdir(dirpath): # Get all files in the subdirectories
                if file.endswith('.shp'): # If it's an .shp.
                    filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                    sfiles.append(fiona.open(filepath))
```

---

When should i add this combination between each shapefiles.schema piece?
if the shapefiles were inserted manually i would do it like this:

```
pst_n=fiona.open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\new\PST')#new pst
pst_o=fiona.open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\old\PST')#old_pst
pst_n.schema
d1 = pst_n.schema['properties']
d2 = pst_o.schema['properties']

d1_items = set(d1.items())
d2_items = set(d2.items())
result = sorted([(k, 'd1', v) for k, v in d1_items if (k, v) not in d2_items] +
                [(k, 'd2', v) for k, v in d2_items if (k, v) not in d1_items])

result = [(k, v, d) for k, d, v in result]


pprint(result)
```

And shows the differences like that:

```
[('ADDRESS', 'int:4', 'd1'),
 ('ADDRESS', 'str:254', 'd2'),
 ('AREA', 'float:19.11', 'd2'),
 ('DEC_ID', 'int:4', 'd1'),
 ('DEC_ID', 'str:254', 'd2'),
 ('DESC_', 'str:254', 'd1'),
 ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9', 'd1'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:50', 'd1'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:12', 'd2'),
 ('LEN', 'float:19.11', 'd2'),
```

Now how should i show each combination's differences as it loops?

The files so you can test if it works is here:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/644y8e12pj9jrei/main_folders.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can drastically simplify your file collection code by using [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to do the collecting; you could use [`fnmatch.filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) to filter down the filenames to only `*.shp` files:

```
import os
import fnmatch

def new_file_paths(rootdir):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
        if dirpath == rootdir: continue. # ignore files in the root
        yield dirpath, [os.path.join(dirpath, fname) for fname in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.shp')]
```

This is a generator function that yields a list of files *per directory*, so you can print information per directory to give to your users. ‘os.walk()` will traverse all subdirectories, at any depth, starting at the root.

If this is an issue, and further nested directories are to be ignored, then using [`glob.iglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) with grouping on the directory name would be simpler:

```
from glob import iglob
from itertools import groupby

def new_file_paths(rootdir):
    # only .shp files in direct subfolders 
    results = igblob(os.path.join(rootdir, '*', '*.shp'))
    return ((d, list(p)) for d, p in groupby(results, key=os.path.dirname))
```

When you loop over the generator object, you can take the *relative* path name of each file in a directory, and check if there is a corresponding file in the other location:

```
rootdir_new = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\a'
rootdir_old = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\k'

for directory, paths in new_file_paths(rootdir_new)):
    if not paths:
        print('{} is empty, no new files found'.format(directory))
        continue

    for path in paths:
        relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, rootdir_new)
        old_path = os.path.join(rootdir_old, relative_path)
        if not os.path.exists(old_path):
            # no corresponding old file
            print('No matching previous version of {}' 
                  'found, skipping'.format(relative_path))
            continue

        # compare `path` with `old_path`
```

As for your comparison code, you can make use of the fact that the [`dict.items()` *dictionary view object*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) is a set, so you can use set operations on those directly without having to call `set()` on them, and sets natively support producing differences. And `sorted()` can take a *key* function, so you can sort your results without having to re-arrange your output list:

```
from operator import itemgetter

d1 = pst_n.schema['properties']
d2 = pst_o.schema['properties']

changed = {'d1': d1.items() - d2.items(), 'd2': d2.items() - d1.items()}
results = sorted(
    ((k, v, d) for d in changed for k, v in changed[d]),
    key=itemgetter(0, 2)) # sort by key, then source. Values will *always* differ.
```

Comment: Ok,that's just an alternative way of doing the already existing first part .Can you answer the actual problem?It looks like you are gonna devise an amazing solution.

Comment: @whwhhw: It's all there now.

Comment: Can you run it?It shows errors to me. first you are closing two parenthesis in the 4th line and if i remove the one it says ths:`File "<ipython-input-21-dad72e1da7e6>", line 6
    print(f'{directory'}) is empty, no new files found')
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` in the location of `}` .

Comment: @whwhhw: right, you are using a Python version older than 3.6. I've removed the `f'...'` string syntax in that case.

Comment: Have you tested it with the files and its ok?What parts should i add if any to work completely?

Comment: I don’t have time right now to validate everything, sorry. What is happening now when you run this?

Comment: Other than that, I’ve already marked where your comparison code goes.

Comment: it says `C:\Users\user\Desktop\a is empty, no new files found` .The process should be to list which properties from the schema are different if they are indeed different  where in this case are so the result is supposed to be the last part of code i posted.Maybe re read the question, you are near the solution i think.

Comment: Right, I added skipping the root folder then. I don’t need to reread the question; the code was deliberately more flexible.

Comment: The last part with the `d1,d2` assigning( was part of my wrong code)should change and should perform the comparison based on the previous code where it compares each new shp with  the corresponding old. As it is now if i print hte results there is no comparison and listing of results based on the 'comparison code'.What is going on?

Comment: @whwhhw: I didn't give you a full solution here; I only gave advice about specific parts of your code. I don't know how `pst_n` and `pst_o` are otherwise assigned.